# Add span to specific words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to add a span to a specific word like this:

```
var value = "eror";
var template = "/(" + value + ")/g";
$("#content").html($("#content").html().replace(template, '<span class="spell_error">$1</span>'));
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xy56M/). I tried using a solution I saw here but it does not seem to work. ANy idea why?
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing regular expression literals and strings.

Use this to create your regex :

```
var template = new RegExp("(" + value + ")", 'g');
```

A regular expression literal is like this :

```
/(something)/
```

There's no quote. But as it is a literal, you can't build it with your code, so that's why you must use the `RegExp` constructor.

A side note : your replacement yould be made lighter and, more importantly, dryer by using the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml) variant taking a function as callback :

```
$("#content").html(function(_,html){
    return html.replace(template, '<span class="spell_error">$1</span>')
});
```

Comment: Ohhh, I messed it up indeed. Thank you! Also thank you for the suggestion of using a callback. much appreciated.